# How to add tooltip on HTML CSS label

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have the code below, how to add tooltip there without using javascript?

```
<input id="albtable1" type="radio" name="albtables" checked="">
<label for="albtable1" class="colorswatch darkgrey"></label>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use "title"

```
<input id="albtable1" type="radio" name="albtables" title="Tooltip usando title" checked="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Gilberto's answer is probably better, but if you want to use css, you could use a pseudo selector.

```css
#albtable1 {
    position: relative;
}

label[for="albtable1"]:hover:not(:focus)::after {
    content: "Tooltip Message";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Way**

Like (@Gilberto B. Terra Jr.) answer, One way you use [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) which will show tooltip.

**CSS Way**

Using CSS, you can do this like below code example but make sure HTML is structured such a way so that you can control in CSS,

```css
label{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip{
  display:none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label:hover .tooltip{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input id="albtable1" type="radio" name="albtables" checked="">
<label for="albtable1" class="colorswatch darkgrey">Checkbox (hover here for tooltip)<span class="tooltip">I'm a tooltip</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found.

```css
<style type="text/css">
.colorswatch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.colorswatch .tooltiptext {
    font-size:9px;
    display:table;
    position:absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: -52px;
    min-width:70px;
    max-width:140px;
    width:120px;
    border:5px solid #afadad;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    height: 30px;
    padding:2px
z-index:99999999999999999;
}
.colorswatch .tooltiptext:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom:-9px;
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #afadad;
border-right:5px solid #afadad;
background:#f3f3f3;
left:50%;
margin-left:-5px;
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform:rotate(45deg);
z-index:101
}

.colorswatch:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

```html
<input id="albtable1" type="radio" name="albtables" checked="">
<label for="albtable1" class="colorswatch darkgrey"><span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></label>
```